# Android - Lifecycle and saving an Instance State questions

Tags: android, lifecycle

So within my application is a form for creating a new user, with relevant details and information about the user.  There's no problems there, it's just what happens when the user leaves the activity without pressing the confirm button.

**Here's what I want to do:**

1. If the user presses the back button, attempt to save all the data to the database and inform the user.
2. If the activity is interrupted (ie by a phone call), save all the data into a temporary location so when the activity is at the top of the stack again, nothing appears to have changed (but the data still hasn't yet been saved to the database).
3. If the activity gets killed for more resources when in the background, do the same as point 2 above (ie when the activity is started again, it appears that nothing has changed).
4. If the whole application is started again (by clicking on the icon again) and there is temporary data stored from either points 2 or 3 above, navigate to the "create user" activity and display data as if nothings changed.

**Here's how I'm currently trying to do it:**

- Use `onDestroy()` and `isFinishing()` functions to find when the activity is being killed, to cover point 1 above (to then try and save all data).
- Save all data with `onSaveInstanceState` into a bundle (to cover point 2 above)
- Does the bundle created with `onSaveInstanceState` survive the activity being killed for more resources, so when its recreated the previous state can be retrieved (as in point 3 above)?
- No idea how to implement point 4.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Are you sure about 3 and 4? It's standard Android behavior for the system to reset your task stack and clear information when the users leaves for a long time, whether the activity is killed or not, so users expect this.

Perhaps a better plan than fighting the system on this is to reduce the amount of non-saveable info on a single screen or redesign the flow so everything can be saved onPause() -- maybe have one screen to create the user with their name, which only saves on clicking a "Create" button, then a 2nd screen to enter details, all of which saves onPause().

Comment: With point 3 and 4 I guess I'm trying to replicate the message application when messages are saved as drafts.  Although cutting up the information into an activity with just the username and other essential details, with other options in another page seems beneficial.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm short on time so can't give a full detailed answer, but in brief, here are my suggestions.

- Instead of using `onDestroy()`, use `onPause()`. That's guaranteed to get called; according to the official documentation on Lifecycles, only onPause() is guaranteed. onStop and onDestroy are not.
- onSaveInstanceState and onPause are similar. Both get called when the app leaves the foreground (i.e. it enters the potential danger zone for being killed), but the difference with oSIS is the temporary bundle it provides. onPause doesn't provide any data storage mechanism, but if you're using a database than you already have one. According to the documentation, there isn't a guaranteed order to which one gets called first.
- Point 3) That's exactly what oSIS is meant for
- Point 4) You could make a 'temporary row' in your database, i.e. save temporary data to row 1, but whenever a save is properly made, row 1 gets blanked. Then in your onCreate(), check whether row 1 has real data or is empty. (If your columns can't be empty, then use pre-determined placeholder values that wouldn't ever appear as part of normal use.)

Comment: A minor correction on your 2nd bullet, according to the documentation for `onSaveInstanceState()`: "There are no guarantees about whether it will occur before or after `onPause()`."

Comment: Also note that onSaveInstanceState() will NOT be called if the activity is finishing (since the user will not be returning to that instance), and you can check isFinishing() in onPause().

Comment: Brilliant thanks for that answer, it covers all bases.  As you say since I have a database, using a bundle doesn't seem completely necessary so creating temporary rows for what I want saved will cover all points.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you create a uniform mechanism to save the temporary state. You can use any of the mechanism suggested by [Android reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) instead of Bundle

Comment: For some reason I hadn't thought of it like this, was blinded by trying to use bundles etc.  This way I'll be in complete control so should be fairly easy to alter if I see fit.