# Data saving during Activity life cycle

Tags: android

What is the common approach to save user's inputed data:
1. Overriding onPause() method with subsequent calling to specially designed method to store data using Android Preferences
OR
2. Usage of onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState()?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually `onPause()` is used to save persistent data and `onSaveInstanceState()` is used to save dynamic data. Note that `onSaveInstanceState()` is not always called before an activity goes to the background.

There is a good explanation for these methods in the documentation of [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Android - Lifecycle and saving an Instance State questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676906/android-lifecycle-and-saving-an-instance-state-questions). As for me, I am doing it in onPause / onCreate. Can't recall if there were problems with the onSaveInstanceState() / onRestoreInstanceState() pair but I think there were.